# How to optimize a generic flood fill algorithm to prevent stack overflow?

Tags: python, stack-overflow, flood-fill

The generic implementation of flood-fill algorithm runs into stack overflow, is there any way to optimize this? I am using this algorithm to find distinct void zones within building models. I voxelize these models then parse through voxelized results reprsented through a simplified version of 0s and 1s. The 0s and 1s represent whether the voxel is present or not. 0s being present and 1s being absent. Then I have to find distinct subsets of connected 0s, in other words, the connected void spaces within the 3D building.

sample 2D input data example stored in list, a 3D would be multiple entries within the list.
(Z, Y, X) = (0, 4, 9)

```
11000111
11000000
10001110
10111110
```

Wikipedia suggested several remedy but I have no idea how to implement them. Here's the existing algorithm, I have already set the "sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)" for much denser data. Which is fine for some, but for even denser ones (Z, Y, X) = (50, 46, 22) or bigger as the building model gets much more complex with hundreds of rooms, I get the stack overflow message

Error stack overflow will happen in the recursive function:

```
File "ZoneFinding3D_Baselined.py", line 104, in findZero
if (0 <= row < row_len) and (0 <= col < col_len) and (0 <= z < height_len) and (col, row, z) not in walked:
MemoryError: Stack overflow
```

Code:

```
    def findZero(subset_in, col, row, z, height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output):
    if (0 <= row < row_len) and (0 <= col < col_len) and (0 <= z < height_len) and (col, row, z) not in walked:
        walked.append((col, row, z))
        if layers3D[z][row][col] == 0: #layers3D is in format (z, row, col) which is the actual hierarchy of input data, Z, Y, X
            if subset_in is not None:
                subset = subset_in
            else:
                subset = []

            subset.append((col, row, z))
            findZero(subset, col+1, row, z,  height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)
            findZero(subset, col, row+1, z,  height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)
            findZero(subset, col-1, row, z,  height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)
            findZero(subset, col, row-1, z,  height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)
            findZero(subset, col, row, z+1,  height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)
            findZero(subset, col, row, z-1,  height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)

            if subset_in is None:
                output.append(subset)

def checkThrough(layers3D, gridSizes):
    walked = []
    output = []
    countX=0; countY=0; countZ=0
    for z in range(0, gridSizes[2]):
        for row in range (countY, countY+gridSizes[1]):
            for col in range (0, gridSizes[0]):
                col_len = gridSizes[0]
                row_len = gridSizes[1]
                height_len = gridSizes[2]

                if (col, row, z) not in walked: #walked takes format of (col, row, z), modified from (z, row, col)
                    findZero(None, col, row, z, height_len, col_len, row_len, layers3D, walked, output)
    return output
```

Comment: use iteration instead of recursion

Comment: Use one of the Alternative implementations discussed in the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations) on the Flood fill algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.label` to do this quickly:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (4, 6))
b = label(a)
print a
print b
```

the output is:

```
[[1 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1]]
(array([[1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3]]), 3)
```

`label()` finds all connected 1s, so you need to reverse 0 & 1 for your data first.